# remove blank facets from ggplot plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a tidy dataframe that I am trying to plot with facet_grid. I would like two rows of plots, the 1st row with 2 plots and the 2nd row with 3 plots. Here is an example of my data with the current plot I am obtaining:

```
dput(data_tidy)
structure(list(player = c("Marvin Williams", "Rudy Gay", "Rajon Rondo", 
"Spencer Hawes", "Marco Belinelli", "Kosta Koufos", "Tyler Hansbrough", 
"Darren Collison", "Omri Casspi", "DeMarcus Cousins", "Jeremy Lin", 
"Kemba Walker", "Ben McLemore", "Troy Daniels", "P.J. Hairston", 
"Willie Cauley-Stein", "Frank Kaminsky", "Marvin Williams", "Rudy Gay", 
"Rajon Rondo", "Spencer Hawes", "Marco Belinelli", "Kosta Koufos", 
"Tyler Hansbrough", "Darren Collison", "Omri Casspi", "DeMarcus Cousins", 
"Jeremy Lin", "Kemba Walker", "Ben McLemore", "Troy Daniels", 
"P.J. Hairston", "Willie Cauley-Stein", "Frank Kaminsky", "Marvin Williams", 
"Rudy Gay", "Rajon Rondo", "Spencer Hawes", "Marco Belinelli", 
"Kosta Koufos", "Tyler Hansbrough", "Darren Collison", "Omri Casspi", 
"DeMarcus Cousins", "Jeremy Lin", "Kemba Walker", "Ben McLemore", 
"Troy Daniels", "P.J. Hairston", "Willie Cauley-Stein", "Frank Kaminsky", 
"Marvin Williams", "Rudy Gay", "Rajon Rondo", "Spencer Hawes", 
"Marco Belinelli", "Kosta Koufos", "Tyler Hansbrough", "Darren Collison", 
"Omri Casspi", "DeMarcus Cousins", "Jeremy Lin", "Kemba Walker", 
"Ben McLemore", "Troy Daniels", "P.J. Hairston", "Willie Cauley-Stein", 
"Frank Kaminsky", "Marvin Williams", "Rudy Gay", "Rajon Rondo", 
"Spencer Hawes", "Marco Belinelli", "Kosta Koufos", "Tyler Hansbrough", 
"Darren Collison", "Omri Casspi", "DeMarcus Cousins", "Jeremy Lin", 
"Kemba Walker", "Ben McLemore", "Troy Daniels", "P.J. Hairston", 
"Willie Cauley-Stein", "Frank Kaminsky"), statistic = c("ft_per_min", 
"ft_per_min", "ft_per_min", "ft_per_min", "ft_per_min", "ft_per_min", 
"ft_per_min", "ft_per_min", "ft_per_min", "ft_per_min", "ft_per_min", 
"ft_per_min", "ft_per_min", "ft_per_min", "ft_per_min", "ft_per_min", 
"ft_per_min", "closestdefenderavg", "closestdefenderavg", "closestdefenderavg", 
"closestdefenderavg", "closestdefenderavg", "closestdefenderavg", 
"closestdefenderavg", "closestdefenderavg", "closestdefenderavg", 
"closestdefenderavg", "closestdefenderavg", "closestdefenderavg", 
"closestdefenderavg", "closestdefenderavg", "closestdefenderavg", 
"closestdefenderavg", "closestdefenderavg", "upr", "upr", "upr", 
"upr", "upr", "upr", "upr", "upr", "upr", "upr", "upr", "upr", 
"upr", "upr", "upr", "upr", "upr", "avgtimeWball", "avgtimeWball", 
"avgtimeWball", "avgtimeWball", "avgtimeWball", "avgtimeWball", 
"avgtimeWball", "avgtimeWball", "avgtimeWball", "avgtimeWball", 
"avgtimeWball", "avgtimeWball", "avgtimeWball", "avgtimeWball", 
"avgtimeWball", "avgtimeWball", "avgtimeWball", "holdshootscore", 
"holdshootscore", "holdshootscore", "holdshootscore", "holdshootscore", 
"holdshootscore", "holdshootscore", "holdshootscore", "holdshootscore", 
"holdshootscore", "holdshootscore", "holdshootscore", "holdshootscore", 
"holdshootscore", "holdshootscore", "holdshootscore", "holdshootscore"
), value = c(123.2, 108.3, 68.9, 135.7, 53.1, 50.7, 83.3, 44.6, 
59.1, 91.6, 71.1, 106.8, 283.5, 53.8, 103.1, 84.8, 73.8, 6.82, 
8.28, 7.64, 6.19, 8.97, 5.97, 4.57, 7.41, 10.13, 6.12, 6.39, 
6.84, 6.59, 8.07, 9.57, 5.36, 7.74, 0.39, 0.41, 0.12, 0.32, 0.58, 
0.11, 0.27, 0.27, 0.36, 0.67, 0.44, 0.36, 0.56, 0.48, 0.28, 0.42, 
0.23, 1.13, 2.04, 4.71, 1.54, 1.57, 1.8, 1.42, 3.78, 1.28, 2.29, 
3.42, 6.22, 1.81, 1.37, 1.66, 0.88, 1.49, 1.99, 3.7, 6.01, 2.52, 
0.92, 3.79, 0.96, 6.18, 2.46, 5.06, 7.6, 15.25, 3.25, 2.05, 5.48, 
1.14, 3.98), this_player = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), statcategory = c("Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", 
"Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", 
"Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", 
"Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", 
"Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Lazy", "Selfish", 
"Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", 
"Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", 
"Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", 
"Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", 
"Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", 
"Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", 
"Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", 
"Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", "Selfish", 
"Selfish", "Selfish")), .Names = c("player", "statistic", "value", 
"this_player", "statcategory"), row.names = c(NA, -85L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the dataframe, it has 5 columns and I am trying to facet on statistic and stat category. I would like the first row of plots to have plots for closestdefenderavg and ft_per_min, and the 2nd row of plots to have the rest. However, in my ggplot call, i receive 10 plots, and there are blank plots spread throughout.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data_tidy, aes(x = reorder(player, -value), y = value, col = this_player, fill = this_player)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        facet_grid(statcategory ~ statistic) + 
        theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
              axis.text.x=element_blank(),
              axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
              axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
        ggtitle("Feet / Minute Players are Running") + 
        theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold", hjust = 0.5))
```

and I obtain the following plots:

[image]

I think I need to structure the dataframe differently, rather than pass extra parameters to the ggplot() call, but I am not sure. I was hoping that getting my data into the data_tidy format above would work, but clearly it hasnt.

Any help appreciated, as always!

Comment: Maybe try `facet_wrap` instead?

Comment: YES!, thank you so much!

Comment: any idea how to center the two bottom plots?

Comment: That's going to be hard. Possible, but will involve manually manipulating the underlying grid grobs.

Comment: okay, not the biggest deal, will probably leave as is. Thanks again for input!